# A single quote ( ' ) in a comment prevented a Vitest mock() function to be implemented. Can someone explain this?

Tags: typescript, debugging, mocking, vitest

I am using `vi.mock()` to mock several methods that use a third party API and node-fetch.

Here is an example of what the code looked like:

```
vi.mock('./path-name', () => {
  return {
    getAllContacts: vi.fn(() => [
    // This contact's tag should be deleted
    ...
    ]
  };
});
```

The exported modules from `./path-name` were not being mocked and all my tests failed.

The solution was to either replace the straight single quote (`'`) quote with a fancy single quote (`’`) or to remove the single quote completely. This is my first time implementing Vitest's mock functionality and I have never seen a bug like this before.

Does anyone have any idea what caused this?